# How to add a non-value attribute in a DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a property on DOM elements using jQuery.

The attribute is disabled, which bootstrap uses this attribute to disable an element. e.g

```
<p>A paragraph</p>
```

and want it to become

```
<p disabled> A paragraph </p>
```

But running the following code

```
$('p').attr('disabled', '');
```

gives me:

```
<p disabled="disabled"><A paragraph</p>
```

Tried using prop() but prop didn't even add the property.

```
$('p').prop('disabled','');
```

How can I add a non-value attribute using jQuery?

Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with a DOM, not with HTML. `disabled` and `disabled="disabled"` are equivalent and there is no way to tell the browser how (when serialising to HTML) it should serialise an attribute which can be serialised in multiple ways.

(`disabled=""` is, last time I checked, invalid)

Answer (score 1):

Try [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$('p').replaceWith(function (_, old) {
    return '<p disabled>' + old + '</p>';
});
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3TFGJ/)</kbd>